# Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit

Tags: gap-system

I tried with the following code snippet in GAP:

```
f:=FreeGroup("P","Q");
g:=f/ParseRelators(f, "P^2 = Q^3=1");
Size(g);
```

But it gets stuck in the following step:

```
gap> Size(g);
#I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit
#I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit
#I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit
#I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit
```

When I terminate the command by `Ctrl-C`, and then run the last command, the following result is returned:

```
brk> Size(g);
16384000
```

Such a simple relationship leads to such a complex group, which makes me a little confused.

Regards,
HZ

Comment: This is an infinite group. How do you see `16384000`? If you did not leave the break loop, then `g` may be pointing to something else.

Comment: I added the `brk>` prompt now, which is where I get my results.

Comment: While at `brk>` prompt, type `g;` to inspect it. I bet it will be a different `g`, not the group above.

Comment: `g;` will display a lot of digits like `154830, 154831, 154832, 154833, 154834, 154835, 154836, 154837, 154838, 154839, 154840, 154841, 154842, 154843,`

Comment: So, it's a list - some intermediate data structure used by the algorithm trying to determine the order of a group. It's infinite, usually repeated "Coset table calculation failed" messages are a sign of that. You need to look at  https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap6.html to better understand what to do with GAP break loops.